# How to correctly Type a React Component that is a param of a Function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a function, which takes two params: a react component, and a string. I am trying to give them correct typings, however, am confused as to why the following wont work...

**The problem is with the typing with GivenComponent in the Function.** By giving the param that specific typing of Component<>, the return of the GivenComponent (within the < Query />) errors stating the following:

*JSX element type 'GivenComponent' does not have any construct or call signatures. [2604]*

However, how would you type that correctly? That param is a React Component, could be both a functional or a class component. As seen in the second part of code, the param isn't given as < MyComponent />, it is given as MyComponent - so not the "rendered" jsx? maybe that changes things

## Function:

**Basically takes a component and returns it with a higher order component wrapper around it**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const withQueryData: Function = (
  GivenComponent: Component<{ data: {} }, any>,
  query: string
) => () => (

  <Query query={gql(query)}>
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
      if (error) return <p>Error! {error.message}</p>;

      return <GivenComponent data={data} />;
    }}
  </Query>
);

export default withQueryData;
```

## React Component:

**example of how the function above is called with params**

```
class MyComponent extends Component<...removed...> {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>...</div>
    );
  }
}



const MyComponentQuery = `query goes here...`;

const MyComponentWithData = withQueryData(
  MyComponent,
  MyComponentQuery
);

export default MyComponentWithData;
```

Comment: Try to use `React.ComponentClass | React.FunctionComponent` instead of `React.Component`

Comment: @LevitatorImbalance but the param can be either class component or functional. I thought ComponentClass indicates it is a Class Component?

Comment: Just reviewed a question and edited my comment)

Comment: Or use `ComponentType`, also don't use `: Function` that disables inference for `withQueryData`

Comment: Also won't you want to forward some props from the wrapper component to the wrapped component ? Your current versions does nto allow any extra props

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transforming my comment into an answer.

There are two typings for declared react components:

`React.ComponentClass` - a typing for react component that is declared as class:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {...} // this is React.ComponentClass
```

`React.FunctionComponent` is a typing for function component (CO to the rescue! :D)

```
const MyFunctionComponent: React.FunctionComponent = props => "something"
```

So, if your component is one of `ComponentClass` or `FunctionComponent`, you can use [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) and tell the TypeScript about it in this way:

```
const SomeUnionType: React.ComponentClass | React.FunctionComponent
```

Thats it! Hope, that helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `ComponentType` to represent a component type (functional or class, defined in react definitions as `type ComponentType<P = {}> = ComponentClass<P> | FunctionComponent<P>;`).

Also you might want to allow the HOC to forward properties from the wrapped component.

Also remove the `Function` annotation from `withQueryData` as that will remove all type safety from `withQueryData`.

```
import { Component, ComponentType } from "react";
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
const withQueryData = <P extends { data: {} }>(
  GivenComponent: ComponentType<P>,
  query: string
) => (p: Omit<P, 'data'>) => (

  <Query query={gql(query)}>
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
      if (error) return <p>Error! {error.message}</p>;

      return <GivenComponent data={data} {...p as any} />;
    }}
  </Query>
);

class MyComponent extends Component<{ data: {}, otherProp: string }> {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>...</div>
    );
  }
}



const MyComponentQuery = `query goes here...`;

const MyComponentWithData = withQueryData(
  MyComponent,
  MyComponentQuery
);

export default MyComponentWithData;

let o = () => <MyComponentWithData otherProp="" ></MyComponentWithData>  // otherProp required, data provided bu the HOC
```